# Fully recursive crawler not working. Only has a 2-3 page crawl depth

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

My goal is to input be able any URL into the `url` variable and have my code then find **all the links** available on the whole entire website.

Currently, my code crawls the original URL... and then it crawls all the links which have been found on page 1. After that point, it stops... so semi recursive. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Please note I'm using HTMLAgilityPack.

Here is my code:

```
    public static List<string> visitedList = new List<string>();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "https://www.bbc.co.uk/";

        crawlOriginalUrl(url);
        visitedList.Add(url);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // get links from provided pages
    public static List<string> getAllLinks(string webAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument newdoc = web.Load(webAddress);

            return newdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                      .Where(y => y.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("http"))
                      .Select(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value)
                      .ToList<string>();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    //crawl the start url and get the first links
    public static void crawlOriginalUrl(string seedSite)
    {
        if (getAllLinks(seedSite) != null)
        {
            var websiteLinks = getAllLinks(seedSite);//get's all the links
            for (int i = 0; i < websiteLinks.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(websiteLinks[i]);
                crawlLinksFound(websiteLinks[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // crawling the links found
    public static void crawlLinksFound(string seedURI)
    {
        if (getAllLinks(seedURI) != null)
        {
            var websiteLinks = getAllLinks(seedURI);//get's all the links
            for (int i = 0; i < websiteLinks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (visitedList.Contains(websiteLinks[i]))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(websiteLinks[i] + " already added.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(websiteLinks[i]);
                    visitedList.Add(websiteLinks[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see this is because your code only crawls one level deep. In `CrawlLinksFound` there is no further call to CrawLinksFound, so all found links will only get added to the visited list, and not processed further.

This kinds for problems are usually solved with recursion. I.e. CrawlLinksFound would call itself with each URI. I usually prefer to use an explicit stack since this avoids potential stackoverflow problems.

This is a example for a generic iterator over a tree:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstNoRevisit<T>(T self, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        var visited = new HashSet<T>();
        stack.Push(self);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            visited.Add(current);
            yield return current;
            foreach (var child in selector(current))
            {
                if (!visited.Contains(child))
                {
                    stack.Push(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You would call it with the initial URL and the method to generate all links for a URL, i.e:

```
foreach(var link = DepthFirstNoRevisit(url, getAllLinks)){
    Console.WriteLine(link)
}
```

Note that this may very well run until you get out of memory. You can also change the Stack to a Queue to iterate in a breadth first order instead of depth first.

Comment: Yeah, depth first seems a bad idea when crawling the internet :-).

Comment: I also think that a standard recursion without an explicit stack would illustrate the principle better. You have to limit recursion depth anyway (and probably to a single-digit depth), so there is no worry of a stack overflow.

Comment: Although this does seem to follow all links, I was wanting to stay on the original domain - but list every link on the original domain crawled. I don't want to follow external links as this would be never ending

Comment: If you want to stay inside the domain, then change 'getAllLinks' to only return links within the same, or a specified domain.

Comment: I still want to list external links, but not follow them. I think the above would follow them

Comment: Then have two 'GetLinks' methods, one to use when crawling over the domain. Then input all crawled links into the second 'GetLinks' method only includes external links.